# ShowCase View sequence

Tags: android, mobile, sequence, showcaseview

I have to implement a Showcase View sequence (important!) on my activity, and this Showcase View seqeunce has to move between the Activity's object (like EditText, TextView, Button, etc..).
I didn't found a lot of documentation, and that documentation doesn't satisfy my need, so I'm gonna ask here if someone knows how to do that.

Thank You all!

Comment: try this: https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView has an example.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it but Android Studio can't resolve the dependecies (I mean compile:"blabla");

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to *@ThinkingMonkey* for that link. It works for me!
A bit late but I hope this could help someone some time.

According to the document of **[Material Showcase View](http://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView)**:

**1.** Add `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` to project's build.gradle under allproject's repositories.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

**2.** Add `compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.1.0@aar'` inside `dependencies {...}` of module's build.gradle.

**3.** Declare targets:

```
        ToggleButton target1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
        TextView target2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Button target3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

**4.** Provide ID if single use.

```
private static final String SHOWCASE_ID = "1";
```

**5.** Here is the sequence code sample of Material Showcase View.

```
ShowcaseConfig config = new ShowcaseConfig();
config.setDelay(500); // half second between each showcase view

MaterialShowcaseSequence sequence = new MaterialShowcaseSequence(this, SHOWCASE_ID);

sequence.setConfig(config);

sequence.addSequenceItem(target1,
                    "This is button one", "GOT IT");

sequence.addSequenceItem(target2,
                    "This is button two", "GOT IT");

sequence.addSequenceItem(target3,
                    "This is button three", "GOT IT");

sequence.start();
```

It's all up to you if you want to put it on `onclick`, `menu options` or `oncreate`.